# How to check SQLite file consistency (health check)

Tags: android, file, sqlite, consistency

I am using a SQLite database file in my Android application that is created from several pieces stored in the assets folder by using the following approach: 
[ReignDesign - Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

On completion of the assemby process I would like to check if the database was correctly merged. The following approaches crossed my mind:

- MD5 hash comparison
- Checking table existence and entry counts

Which approach would you recommend? Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation in an application I'm developing. There are a variety of ways of doing it; but in the end I stopped worrying about what exactly and how to best measure database integrity, and instead focused on 'is my database usable by my application'.

So basically I test whether: 1) I can open the SQLite database properly 2) I can perform queries on the database and 3) Whether the result for a pre-defined query returns what is expected.

So basically: include a table with a record of known ID that gives a value that you know, then try to read that value. Checking the table count can't hope.

That said I'm hoping someone here with a good knowledge of DB systems will explain a) exactly what `PRAGMA integrity_check` does and b) how reliable it is and how efficient it is compared with manual table checks.

Comment: I now use `PRAGMA integrity_check` plus a MD5 checksum test to validate the integrity of my database. Generating the MD5 checksum is reasonably fast, while using SHA-1 took to long in my opinion. Doing manual entry checks like you suggest is probably the only way to be really sure. Still it is quite a lot of work to implement them.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check.

Answer (score 4):

In Api 11, **SQLiteDatabase** has a method **isDatabaseIntegrityOk** for checking integrity of SQLite databases :

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isDatabaseIntegrityOk()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isDatabaseIntegrityOk%28%29)

And source code is avaible here :

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr1-release/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#L2585

It's easy to backport on old devices.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer second approach on the first one both with respect to performance and ease of coding.