# Check integrity of Database SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database file in my server, and from time to time my Android App checks if there is a new SQLite database file. If true the App downloads the File and replaces the old database.

The problem is, that some times the new database file gets corrupted and the App start to crashing and never recovers if I dont manualy clean the app in the Android Settings.

My question is, there is a way to check the integrity of SQLite Database after the Downloaded?

This is my code for download the new Database from the server this code is placed in an AssyncTask :

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... Url) {
        try {
                URL url = null;
                if(Url[0].equals("")){
                    mSyncDate = mConnectionManager.getSyncDate();
                    url = new URL(Constants.HF_SERVER_DATABASE+"db_fxbus_"+convertDateToFormatYYYYMMDD(mSyncDate.getServerDate())+".sqlite");
                }else{
                    url = new URL(Url[0]);
                }
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                mDB.getReadableDatabase();
                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                Log.i(TAG, "Path:"+mContext.getDatabasePath("HorariosDoFunchal").getAbsolutePath());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mContext.getDatabasePath("HorariosDoFunchal").getAbsolutePath());
                startWriting = true;
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Executing ...");
                }
                //Log.i(TAG, "Finish ...");

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you can create a MD5 hash at the server and send it along the new database and then check it with your downloaded db. look into [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5404925/3326331) it talks about the same database integrity issue

Comment: Why are you downloading a script that can modify the database on the phone.  IE alter table add column, updates, inserts, delete, etc.  The script could also test itself with a known results from a query as @SagarPilkhwal link points out.

Comment: I know, I had that but sometimes the Database takes to long in performing many changes to update and delete and insert the modifications. To the server do that its much more faster. Than saves into a file and the app checks for updates from time to time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into:

```
pragma integrity_check;
```

it will scan the Database and check it for errors and other things too.
More info(and more commands) can be found at this link:

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html

also check out the documentation of [isDatabaseIntegrityOk()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isDatabaseIntegrityOk%28%29).

Comment: I think that could work but now I have another problem how I save the old database in a temporary location in case the new database is corrupted I can recovery my database?

Comment: When you copy the new database, just rename the old database, if the new database works then delete the renamed old database, otherwise if the new database doesn't work delete the new database and rename old database back to its original name

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) (or Android's equivalent [isDatabaseIntegrityOk()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#isDatabaseIntegrityOk%28%29)), but this checks only the database structure for errors, and can detect only errors where it can prove that the structure is wrong.

To be able to detect all errors (especially in your own data), you need to compute a checksum for the entire database file.

Comment: I think that could work but now I have another problem how I save the old database in a temporary location in case the new database is corrupted I can recovery my database?